# Symfony2 Web Service

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently designing a new web application based on Symfony Framework that will serve both web and mobile accesses. For illustration purposes I will use the default AcmeDemoBundle from Symfony`s framework to elaborate my question.

So, DemoBundle gives me the following route:

```
/hello/{name}
```

So far so good. Now, I want to implement an API in this project that will serve mobile apps, so the route for the same controller as the route above whould be, for instance:

```
/api/v1/hello/{name}
```

My doubt is: what's the best way of doing that without replicating code? I intend to use the FOSRestBundle for the API and I know that he handles rendering HTML views to, but I'd like to separate the API routes from the web as I put before. Maybe should I create a new bundle for the API?

Comment: It really depends on your purposes. Separate bundle for API looks good decision. But if you need both (web and api) to return the same data (but in different format) it's not a good idea, I think, because with any change you will have to make changes twice.
You can use {format} in your route to manage possible ways of rendering or something.

Comment: Yes, what you said about not being a good idea separate the bundle API makes sense... But although FOSRestBundle treat the routes with the {format} parameter it's not exactly what I want since the routes will be the same for both web and API, differentiated only by the {format}.. But I will take a look more deeply on the bundle documentation about the routes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a bundle for the API is not a good practice for the simple reason that you can't easily re-use the bundle in an other project.

For example, you create PostBundle and his API bundle, APIPostBundle for your A project.
If you want to use that bundle for a B project, you need PostBundle and APIPostBundle. You created dependency between two bundles and it's a bad practice [(Component-Based Development).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering)

So, you have to generate an independency bundle with a strength architecture who can allow you less modification if you have to. 
Use a service for the logical instructions. Then, the `controller/APIController` can manage the route and will call the service methods. By that way, you can just modify the service without editing the controllers.

So, your architecture looks like that:

```
PostBundle
  Controller
    - PostController
    - APIPostController 
  Service
    - PostService
    - PostServiceInterface
```

Comment: Thanks Gura, I will try your suggestion... I think that this approach with services fits better at what I need since I can treat the routes with more versatility and more independency between web application and API.